# Drill bits for metal work? Why cant I seem to find ones that last?

Tags: tools, metal, welding, drill-bit

Looking for some recommendations on drill bits for use with metal.
I have a decent Drill Press that has a 500-3100RPM range, I use oil, etc.
I’ve been trying to drill 3/8” holes in T-Bar Fence posts/stakes. I buy the metal bits, all flavors of them and I can only seem to get 2-3 holes per bit before they become useless.

Is it the bits? Is it me? I’m not sure.
I’ve tried the spendy *RED HELIX™ Cobalt Drill Bit* from Milwaukee and I still cant seem to get a decent number of holes per bit.

I watch these welding videos on Instagram and they are drilling and drilling, thats what I want!

Thanks!

Comment: low speed and do not push

Comment: Have you had a similar experience with drilling other steel items with similar hole sizes and thicknesses? Or is it just the fence posts as far as you know?

Comment: The workpiece is well secured? There's not a ton of vibration while you're drilling?

Comment: Are you using the right feeds and speeds? If you go too fast you wreck the bit from heat, if you go too slow you work harder the material and then full the bit.

Comment: If you do everything right, (and hopefully others will tell you what that means) you may achieve what you want.  Me, I'm in your shoes and I'm trying to get better but I don't have a press, and sometimes I'm sadly impatient or, IDK, incompetent?  I bought a $75 bit sharpener and it has helped a LOT.  On difficult jobs or when drilling holes where errors would be costly, I sharpen the bit before each hole.  It takes seconds and has helped me a lot.  IT's not THE answer but til you become a lot better at it, it helps.

Comment: The right speed, the right feed, _and_ the right cutting fluid

Comment: Pre-drilling with an 1/8" bit couldn't hurt either.

Comment: What kind of paint on these fence posts? Is it the kind of fancy textured paint that has grains of sand in it?

Comment: What sort of metal? You imply some sort of steel, but you don't state it explicitly and it makes a big difference. Brass and aluminium are easy, mild steel not too bad so long as you don't get the bit too hot, but stainless steel is tricky

Comment: What kind of chips are coming out? One continuous band?

Comment: Those (steel, not stainless) fence posts are made in a process that results in them being typically very hard. The hardness can vary with what scrap metal they are dumping in the furnace, but in general, hard as bleep. You could try anealing the spot you want to drill. You could (if you have things set up VERY rigidly) try a tungsten carbide bit (if everything is not very rigid, you may shatter that - they are hard, but brittle.)